# Facebook v2.2/me/groups return "error_code": -3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to get groups for some users, Facebook API returns the following error:

> {   "error_code": -3,    "error_msg": "Please reduce the amount of
>   data you're asking for, then retry your request" }

Could anyone help me? How should I rewrite the request to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe those users have _a lot_ of groups. Try using the `limit` parameter in your request to request only a certain number of groups and see if that solves the problem, and if so from there on use pagination to get the “rest”.

Comment: Smaller page sizes fixed it for me.